# Multiple django 'with' statements inside 'if' statement

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have a Django multiple 'with' statements inside 'if/elif' statement.
The blocks of code inside if/elif are the same except for one variable 'slide1_line2'.
I am wondering if there is a way to re-write code to avoid repetition.

```
{% if country == 'England' or country == 'Wales'%}              
{% with graphic='map.png' %}
{% with classes='color-1' %}
{% with slide1_line1='Your constituency is '|add:name %}
{% with slide1_line2='Heading1' %}
{% with slide1_line3='text' %}
{% with icon='keyboard_arrow_down' %}
{% include 'slide_map.html' %}
{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}

{% elif country == 'Scotland' or country == 'Northern Ireland' %}               
{% with graphic='map.png' %}
{% with classes='color-1' %}
{% with slide1_line1='Your constituency is '|add:name %}
{% with slide1_line2='Heading2' %}
{% with slide1_line3='text' %}
{% with icon='keyboard_arrow_down' %}
{% include 'slide_map.html' %}
{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}{% endwith %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Define the common `with`s outside the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor out the common values outside the `if` statement:

```
{% with graphic='map.png' classes='color-1' slide1_line1='Your constituency is '|add:name slide1_line3='text' icon='keyboard_arrow_down' %}
  {% if country == 'England' or country == 'Wales' %}
    {% include 'slide_map.html' with slide1_line2='Heading1' %}
  {% else %}
    {% include 'slide_map.html' with slide1_line2='Heading2' %}
  {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Note that:

1. you can define multiple variables in the same [**`{% with … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with); and
2. the [**`{% include … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) can have a `{% include … with … %}` clause to pass certain extra parameters.

Comment: The above solution prints below statement in the browser.
'
{% if country == 'England' or country == 'Wales'%}
{% include 'tactical/slides/slide_map.html' with slide1_line2='Heading1' %}
'

However, with/endwith renders template correctly.
'
{% if country == 'England' or country == 'Wales'%}
{% with slide1_line2='Heading1' %}
{% include 'tactical/slides/slide_map.html' %}
{% endwith %}
'

Does it have something to go with the version? I am using Django 2.2.6.

Comment: @GeoMeteoMe: I tested this locally, and it works (version 2.2.2). Although strictly speaking possible, I would really be surprised if 2.2.6 handles it differently. Are you sure you did not make a typo, etc. in the template?

Comment: I just upgraded Django to 2.2.7 and it doesn't make any difference. 
I discovered though that whatever is between **{% ... %}** brackets has to be in one line.
If **{% with .. %}** is split between multiple lines you will get the following error:
_Invalid block tag on line 25: 'endwith', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?_
If **{% include.. with .. %}** is split between multiple lines the statement gets printed as a string.